# Errors when using framework on Obj-C lang. via CocoaPods for Swift project (can't run project either on simulator nor on device)

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I have some code on Objective-C language compiled into fat lib for all architectures and then packaged into framework.

My goal is to use this framework in Swift project via CocoaPods. Actually to publish this framework via CocoaPods.

The problem: when I publish this framework into local Pod and import it into Swift project I can't run it either on simulator or on device.

- for simulator I have this error:

  > "The operation couldn't be completed. LaunchServicesError error 0."
- for device I have this error:

  > "App installation failed. Could not inspect the application package"

In the Pod I use "Resources" folder only with framework itself. And I use this line in the podspec file

```
`s.resources = ['Resources/*.*']`
```

For Podfile I use this line (I use local just to try if it works)

```
`pod ‘podname’, :git => 'pod_git_url'`
```

Then I manually create bridging header file and specify it in the

```
`Build Settings > Objective-C Bridging Header`
```

then add import for framework in the bridging file

```
`#import <FrameworkName/HeaderClass.h>`
```

And also I add the framework into `Link Binary With Libraries`
As a result it gives the mentioned errors.

Interesting though that if I import the mentioned framework directly in the the project, without using CocoPods - it works like a charm.
But it doesn't via CocoaPods.

P.S. My project in Swift language is in old syntax - so when I open it after adding Pods it asks me to convert it to either Swift 3 or Swift 2.3. I selected 2.3. Could it be the source of the problem?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning pod cache...run "pod cache clean"....from SRC_ROOT run "rm -rf Pods" and "rm Podfile.lock"...reset simulator...clean project and remove derived data.

Comment: doesn't help - the same error present

Comment: If I add the framework manually to `Embedded Binaries` - then I've got another error: `fmaeworkName.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
 `

Comment: I think you should rename the "Resources" folder from your pod to something else. "Assets" or "Images" maybe. Delete the derived data, delete pods directory, install pod again and clean build project.

Comment: thank you for the tip. Found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

Actually RoHan's tip got me thinking in a right way. Previously I've put the `.framework` file inside `Resources` folder and specified it accordingly. So framework file itself was not linked the correct way as part of Pod.

The solution is to specify framework file as `s.vendored_frameworks` in a `.podspec`, like this:

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'FrameworkName.framework'
```

That's it. Works like a charm.

P.S. Don't forget to use bridging header file if you use your framework (on objc lang) in swift project

Comment: Glad I could help.